# How to speed up code for calculating climate data percentiles

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

```
import os
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

data_folder1 = 'K:\\reanalysis\ERA5\\100m_speed\\100m u\\1979-2022'
data_folder2 = 'K:\\reanalysis\ERA5\\100m_speed\\100m v\\1979-2022'

file_names_u = os.listdir(data_folder1)
file_names_v = os.listdir(data_folder2)

def read_wind(file_path_u, file_path_v, lat_value, lon_value):
    with xr.open_dataset(file_path_u) as ds:
        u_wind = ds['u100'].sel(latitude=lat_value, longitude=lon_value).values
    with xr.open_dataset(file_path_v) as ds:
        v_wind = ds['v100'].sel(latitude=lat_value, longitude=lon_value).values
    return u_wind, v_wind

lat_value = 0
lon_value = 90
all_u_winds = []
all_v_winds = []

for file_name_u, file_name_v in zip(file_names_u, file_names_v):
    file_path_u = os.path.join(data_folder1, file_name_u)
    file_path_v = os.path.join(data_folder2, file_name_v)
    u_wind, v_wind = read_wind(file_path_u, file_path_v, lat_value, lon_value)
    all_u_winds.extend(u_wind)
    all_v_winds.extend(v_wind)

all_u_winds = np.array(all_u_winds)
all_v_winds = np.array(all_v_winds)

# 计算风速
all_windspeeds = np.sqrt(np.square(all_u_winds) + np.square(all_v_winds))

percentile_50 = np.percentile(all_windspeeds, 50)
print(f"The 50% percentile of the wind speed values is: {percentile_50}")
```

I want to calculate the wind speed percentile of a latitude and longitude grid point in my nc file for 44 years. One of my files is 1.4G, with a total of 528 u and 528 v files, but it is very slow for me to calculate with my current code. Could you please help me see how to improve it

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a profiler such as pyinstrument to find the slowest parts of your code.  I've added the required lines to your code to use pyinstrument (see below).  Start with just a few of your data files.  After you find and fix the main bottlenecks, try running your code with more data files.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from pyinstrument import Profiler

profiler = Profiler()
profiler.start()

data_folder1 = 'K:\\reanalysis\ERA5\\100m_speed\\100m u\\1979-2022'
data_folder2 = 'K:\\reanalysis\ERA5\\100m_speed\\100m v\\1979-2022'

file_names_u = os.listdir(data_folder1)
file_names_v = os.listdir(data_folder2)

def read_wind(file_path_u, file_path_v, lat_value, lon_value):
    with xr.open_dataset(file_path_u) as ds:
        u_wind = ds['u100'].sel(latitude=lat_value, longitude=lon_value).values
    with xr.open_dataset(file_path_v) as ds:
        v_wind = ds['v100'].sel(latitude=lat_value, longitude=lon_value).values
    return u_wind, v_wind

lat_value = 0
lon_value = 90
all_u_winds = []
all_v_winds = []

for file_name_u, file_name_v in zip(file_names_u, file_names_v):
    file_path_u = os.path.join(data_folder1, file_name_u)
    file_path_v = os.path.join(data_folder2, file_name_v)
    u_wind, v_wind = read_wind(file_path_u, file_path_v, lat_value, lon_value)
    all_u_winds.extend(u_wind)
    all_v_winds.extend(v_wind)

all_u_winds = np.array(all_u_winds)
all_v_winds = np.array(all_v_winds)

# 计算风速
all_windspeeds = np.sqrt(np.square(all_u_winds) + np.square(all_v_winds))

percentile_50 = np.percentile(all_windspeeds, 50)
print(f"The 50% percentile of the wind speed values is: {percentile_50}")

profiler.stop()
profiler.print()
```